# Image Upload without Multer in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How can I upload and store images in MongoDB without using Multer/any other middleware? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use request data stream or pipe it to some other stream something like `fs.createWriteStream`, here is code example:

```
request.on('data', (data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can implement it in your code. Middleware such as Multer implements this functionality. So you can do it too. Multer implement over busboy you can check their implementation in their repositories - [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) and [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy). Source code is good way for study.
Or see how pipe data from request and you can receive it in your middleware.

```
req.on('data', data => {
   // ... do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible.

Instead of `multer` use [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy). And for file storing in mongoDB database, check [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

Answer (score 0):

Install `npm install --save express-fileupload`

**In the app.js/server.js file do this**

```
const upload = require('express-fileupload');
// Then you can set a middleware for express-fileupload
app.use(upload());
```

You can see the full example of how to do this [here](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/tree/master/example).

After doing this you can save the location(url) of your file in mongoDB for referencing it later in a web page.

To know how to access the properties of the file you are uploading eg: fileName etc... see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload). Good luck